# What layout is this 3D 360 video YouTube served my browser?

Tags: video, youtube

I fetched a 3D 360 video from YouTube at the highest quality, and found it to be in a layout which I have not yet heard of.

Does anyone know the proper way to deal with this layout?

[image: unique layout]

I thought it looked like a unique kind of "cube map", but it turns out it isn't, because when you try to treat it as one, the image distorts towards the edges.

[image: image distortion]

Comment: It probably is distorted to account for the distortion from the lenses used in VR glasses.

Comment: I mean, I'm viewing it in VR glasses... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Someone hit me up out of band with the answer last night.

https://blog.google/products/google-vr/bringing-pixels-front-and-center-vr-video/

I still don't have any good way to convert the videos, but this I guess answers the initial question.